# Forcing PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP To Complete When Using Make Multithreaded

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

Given a simple cmake file such as

`PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP( ProtoSources ProtoHeaders Example.proto )
ADD_LIBRARY( Example SHARED Example.cpp )`

is there a way force the PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP to complete before the next step begins when using `make -j8`?

(Context: when using `cmake . ; make -j8` on a cmake file, the first run almost always fails because the protobuf files havn't finished processing by the time the library is being compiled. The second run always works fine but it would be nice to avoid having to run make twice everytime.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that 'Example' depends on ProtoSources and/or ProtoHeaders.
Otherwise the build order wouldn't matter.

You will need to tell CMake that there is a dependency between 'Example' and the generated files.

Try adding these lines to your script

```
add_custom_target(generated_code DEPENDS ${ProtoSources} ${ProtoHeaders})
add_dependencies(Example generated_code)
```

Comment: That is what I needed. Thank you.